# How to think about yield for a annuity of fixed number of years which pays a predefined cashflow each year

Tags: yield

Let's say I have an offer to pay $1000 now and for the next 20 years, I will receive the following payments:

```
Year 1: $10
Year 2: $20
Year 3: $30
Year 4: $40
Year 5: $50
Year 6: $60
Year 7: $70
Year 8: $80
Year 9: $90
Year 10: $100
Year 11: $110
Year 12: $120
Year 13: $130
Year 14: $140
Year 15: $150
Year 16: $160
Year 17: $170
Year 18: $180
Year 19: $190
Year 20: $200
```

How do I calculate the "yield" of such an offer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As user662852 says, use IRR:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Internal_rate_of_return

[image]

Set all the cash flows to net present value (NPV)

```
-1000 + 10/(1 + r) + 20/(1 + r)^2 + . . . + 200/(1 + r)^20 = 0
```

Solve for `r`

```
r = 5.88671%
```

Answer (score 6):

Since they occur on equal intervals, use the IRR() function for [Internal Rate of Return](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/irr-function-64925eaa-9988-495b-b290-3ad0c163c1bc) in Excel or the equivalent in your favorite spreadsheet program.  The first entry would be -1000, and then 10, 20, ..., 200 as listed above.  I get 6%